# Javascript call() on anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand one of the examples on MDN for `Function.prototype.call()`,   ["Using call() to invoke an anonymous function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#using_call_to_invoke_an_anonymous_function):

```
const animals = [
  { species: 'Lion', name: 'King' },
  { species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail' }
];

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    this.print = function() {
      console.log('#' + i + ' ' + this.species
                  + ': ' + this.name);
    }
    this.print();
  }).call(animals[i], i);
}
```

Is the `i` at line #7 `(function(i) {` a repetition/optional?

It seemed to me that `}).call(animals[i], i);` at line #12 with the second parameter is already passing `i`, so to make my test, I wanted to remove it

I mean that at line #7, instead of `(function(i) {` I have tried `(function() {` and as I was supposing, it gives the same result.

Comment: Yes, `i` did not have to be passed as a parameter.

Comment: It's optional, but **not** because it's "already passing" on line 12 - the parameter is there to receive the second argument to call - rather because it's in scope from the for loop. Try _renaming_ the parameter, e.g. `(function(index) {` then `'#' + index`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe to kindly recap: `this.`, as explained in the documentation, it's taken from the first parameter of line #12, in this case animals[], while the 'i' in `function(i)` is optional and it is the part that accepts the second parameter , the 'i' in line #12 , correct? Thank you for explanations

Answer (score 0):

Thank too Jonsharpe I clarified myself the mechanism

Since this was a didactic question , I share the explicitation to students like me

first of all, the code is misleading, so to better understand it, as suggested by Jonsharpe it is better to replace 'i' with 'index'

```
const animals = [
    { species: 'Lion', name: 'King' },
    { species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail' }
  ];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      this.print = function() {
        console.log('#' + index + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name);
      }
      this.print();
    }).call(animals[i], i);
  }
```

how should it be read, with a paraphrase it does mean

`.call` the `function(index)` passing it `(animals[i], i)` as parameters

the first parameter, an object, is then available through `this.` the second is passed through `index`

At line #8 is added and defined a method 'print' to the object

At line #11 this new method is run/called `this.print();`

The process is repeated `animals.length` times